# Como carregar apenas o dado em si do banco de dados no ComboBox?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, combobox

Meu `Combobox` está apresentando os dados armazenados no banco de forma errada, quando eu clico nele,  ao invés de aparecer unicamente o nome dos supostos clientes cadastrados, o `Combobox` apresenta o nome do pacote, da classe e uma gama de letras e números.

Trecho de código responsável por carregar o Combobox:

```
public void carregarComboBoxCliente() {
    ObservableList<Cliente> observableListaCliente = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            this.clienteListaController.retornaListagemCliente());
    
    this.cbxClientes.setItems(observableListaCliente);
}
```

Trecho de código do retornaListagemCliente:

```
public List<Cliente> retornaListagemCliente(){
    
    if(this.getClienteDAO()==null) {
        this.setClienteDAO(new ClienteDAO());
    }
    
    return this.getClienteDAO().getAll();
}
```

Código da classe(entidade) Cliente:

```
public class Cliente {

//atributos
private Long id;
private String nome;
private String email;
private Date dataCadastro;
private String cpf;

//getters e setters
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

Obs: A classe cliente possui apenas métodos "getters e setters" de seus respectivos atributos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgFOd.png)

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: @Danizavtz já editei a pergunta conforme pedido.

Comment: Eu coloquei uma resposta, poderia verificar se resolve o seu problema? Escrevi de uma maneira que a solução fica genérica assim você pode implementar sozinho. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é implementando o método `toString()` da classe que deseja exibir no elemento da interface `combobox`.

Para entender o que está acontecendo considere o seguinte exemplo:

***Pessoa.java***

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;

    //construtor
    public Pessoa(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    //setter
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    //getter
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Ao usar esta classe e tentar imprimir o conteúdo dessa classe no console, então temos o seguinte resultado:

***main.java***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa("eu");
        System.out.println(p);
        //com.example.stckovrflw.Pessoa@254989ff
        //que também é equivalente à 
        System.out.println(p.toString());
        //com.example.stckovrflw.Pessoa@254989ff
    }
```

Repare que é uma saída bem parecido com o que está obtendo em seu programa. Outro ponto é que em nenhum momento na declaração da classe `Pessoa` foi implementado o método toString, mas mesmo assim foi possível executar este método em meu objeto.

Isso acontece porque em Java toda classe é direta ou indiretamente uma subclasse de `Object`. [`Ref`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). Assim todas as classes herdam esta implementação que foi feita na classe `Object`. O método toString() possui uma implementação "padrão" em que o classpath é concatenado com o endereço de memória que aponta para o conteúdo deste objeto. Como podemos ver a implementação do método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString) da classe `Object`.
Implementação concreta do método toString() da classe `Object`.

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Agora que sabemos o motivo de imprimir desta forma, o que você pode fazer para resolver este problema é implementar o método toString() da classe `Cliente`.

Para o exemplo da classe Pessoa, uma implementação possível seria:

```
public String toString() {
    return this.nome;
}
```

Após fazer esta implementação toda vez que eu for fazer um *"print"* deste objeto, o resultado será:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pessoa p = new Pessoa("eu");
    System.out.println(p);
    //eu
    System.out.println(p.toString());
    //eu
}
```

Repare que eu só começo a obter este resultado após implementar o método toString() na classe `Pessoa` pois desta forma eu estou sobre-escrevendo (*override*) a implementação padrão (herdada da classe `Object`).

Answer (score 2):

Utilizei o método toString() na classe Cliente e consegui solucionar esse problema.

Código da classe Cliente, onde apenas foi acrescentado o método toString():

```
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.nome;
}
```

Resultado na tela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Parabéns, muito bom.

Answer (score 0):

Você está imprimindo apenas a referência da memória... Isso acontece quando voce chama o objeto na página mas ele não tem um toString.

Voce tem duas opções

1- Criar um toString na classe Cliente
2- Chamar apenas o getCliente.getNome() na página, aconselho a usar essa segunda opção, a não ser que você necessite de todas as informações do cliente na tela.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).